# Google App Engine passing nested values to template

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to create a web app with GAE and the data structure consists of Dockets, Projects and Tasks.

Each docket has multiple projects and each project has multiple tasks in turn. On the docket page I need to display all the content under a docket, so:

- Project 1: task a, task b, task c, ....
- Project 2: task a, task c, task c, ....
  and so on...

I managed to get all the Projects displayed in a list using the following code, but am lost when it comes to displaying the tasks under each project. Being a complete novice in GAE, python and web apps I do not even know about terminology to search for and my searches didn't help out much....maybe someone here can help.

```
class DocketPage(BaseRequestHandler):
_OUTPUT_TYPES = {
'default': ['text/html', 'html'],
}

def get(self):
 docket = Docket.get(self.request.get('id'))
 docket_name = docket.name
 if not docket:
   self.error(403)
   return

projects_query = Project.all().ancestor(
            docket)
projects = projects_query.fetch(10)

for project in projects:
    tasks_query = Task.all().ancestor(project)
    tasks = tasks_query.fetch(10) 

# Choose a template based on the output type
output_name = self.request.get('output')
output_name_list = DocketPage._OUTPUT_TYPES.keys()
if output_name not in output_name_list:
  output_name = output_name_list[0]
output_type = DocketPage._OUTPUT_TYPES[output_name]

self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = output_type[0]
self.generate('docket_' + output_name + '.' + output_type[1], {
  'docket': docket,
  'projects': projects,
  'tasks' : tasks,
})
```

I managed to get the taks to display in the template by altering the code in the following manner. This however doesn't obviously help because the number of projects and tasks can not to be known.

```
tasks_query = Task.all().ancestor(projects[0])
tasks = tasks_query.fetch(10)
```

Comment: What template engine? What's `self.generate()` do? Also, please fix your indentation.

Comment: Actually I managed to figure it out myself. Just needed to pass all taks into the template and then filter them using an if statement to make sure they have the appropriate parent.

Comment: of course a better way to do this is by using collections to create a relationship between project and tasks. Say if you name the collections of Task as `tasks`, then you can access all the appropriate tasks by using `projects.tasks`